# How to divide a continuous variable into defined intervals with top interval up to infinity using h2o

Tags: r, h2o

I am using the cut function to divide a continuous variable into intervals (0 -1, 2 - 3, 3 - 4, 4+). I am specifically having issues defining the last interval which I want to have an upper bound of infinity. In base **R**, I can define an upper bound of infinity using "Inf"

Here's an example which throws an error while using h2o.

```
input_data <- as.h2o(seq(0.1, by = 0.1, 100))
names(input_data) <- 'var1'
breaks <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, Inf)
cut(input_data[['var1']], breaks = breaks, right = TRUE)
```

I receive an error:

> "breaks must be a numeric vector"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve